# How to copy a nested list and change elements of the nested list without changing the original list?

Tags: python

I would like to copy the following list:

```
startTimeList = [[0, 0], [2, 0], [4, 0], [6, 0], [8, 0], [10, 0], [12, 0], [14, 0], [16, 0], [18, 0], [20, 0], [22, 0]]
```

Then store this copy of startTimeList as a list called endTimeList. And subsequently change this copy so that the every last element of the nested list (which is currently 0) is changed to the value of a variable called flowDuration (which is now set at 10).

Then the endTimeList should look like this:

```
[[0, 10], [2, 10], [4, 10], [6, 10], [8, 10], [10, 10], [12, 10], [14, 10], [16, 10], [18, 10], [20, 10], [22, 10]]
```

This is the code I have for this right now:

```
startTimeList = [[0, 0], [2, 0], [4, 0], [6, 0], [8, 0], [10, 0], [12, 0], [14, 0], [16, 0], [18, 0], [20, 0], [22, 0]] # the initial list that has to be transformed into endTimeList
flowDuration = 10

endTimeList = startTimeList.copy() # copies the startTimesList and stores this copy as endTimesList

for y in endTimeList: 
    y[1] = flowDuration # for every nested list in the startTimeList, changes the first index (which is the second element of the nested list) into a variable called flowDuration (which is currently 10)

print(startTimeList)
print(endTimeList)
```

However, when I run this code, somehow startTimeList has also changed from its original values, while this list should stay the same. These are the values of startTimeList en endTimeList that I get when I print them:

```
startTimeList: [[0, 10], [2, 10], [4, 10], [6, 10], [8, 10], [10, 10], [12, 10], [14, 10], [16, 10], [18, 10], [20, 10], [22, 10]]

endTimeList: [[0, 10], [2, 10], [4, 10], [6, 10], [8, 10], [10, 10], [12, 10], [14, 10], [16, 10], [18, 10], [20, 10], [22, 10]]
```

and these would be the desired values:

```
startTimeList: [[0, 0], [2, 0], [4, 0], [6, 0], [8, 0], [10, 0], [12, 0], [14, 0], [16, 0], [18, 0], [20, 0], [22, 0]]
endTimeList: [[0, 10], [2, 10], [4, 10], [6, 10], [8, 10], [10, 10], [12, 10], [14, 10], [16, 10], [18, 10], [20, 10], [22, 10]]
```

How can it be possible that the startTimeList is also altered, while I made sure to only edit the copy called endTimeList?

Comment: You made a _shallow copy_.

Comment: "copy" only makes a shallow copy (only outer list is copied). Use "copy.deepcopy" instead.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, objects are passed by reference, which means that changes to an object will affect all the references of that object. When you copy a `list`, it creates a shallow copy, meaning only the top level of items is copied - the references to the inner lists still point to the same place. If you want to copy everything in the list, you want to use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

endTimeList = deepcopy(startTimeList)
```

Comment: And [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy) have a good explanation of shallow and deep copies too

Answer (score 1):

That's the way to do what you want:

```
import copy
endTimeList = copy.deepcopy(startTimeList)
```